# The Product of Consecutive Integers is Never a Power: Lemma 1 (Research Paper Study)

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, divisibility

P. Erdos and J. L. Selfridge proved in the  paper [THE PRODUCT OF CONSECUTIVE INTEGERS IS NEVER A POWER (click here)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256050816), that the equation $(n + 1) \cdots(n + k)=x^l \cdots (1)$ has no solution in integers with $k > 2, l > 2, n > 0$. There is a lemma $1$, I have $2$ issues (**for better searchability for future reader, I asked in single post**).

(i) Please read the following paragraph writtten on page 293 -

> First observe that by the well-known theorem of Sylvester and Schur, there is always a prime greater than >$k$ which divides $(n + 1)... (n + k)$, since $n > k$. Such a prime divides only one of the $k$ factors,
> so $n + k > (k + 1)^l$, whence $n > k^l \cdots (2)$.

If equation $(1)$ is true I understand  $n + k > (k + 1)^l$ since there is a prime greater than $> k$ and that prime must have power $l$. But how do we derive  $$n > k^l?$$

I mean,  $n + k > (k + 1)^l$ is independent of  $n > k^l$, then how this two inequalities are related?

(ii) On page 294 it is written that -

$$ l\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} (\frac{kl}{2n})^{i-1}= \frac{kl^2}{2n-kl}$$

If geometric series is used then it should be $ l\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} (\frac{kl}{2n})^{i-1}= l \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{kl}{2n}} = l \cdot \frac{2n}{2n-kl}$ (by multiplying $\frac{2n}{2n}$), not $\frac{kl^2}{2n-kl}$.

So questions are: why $n > k^l$ and $ l\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} (\frac{kl}{2n})^{i-1}= \frac{kl^2}{2n-kl}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) is evident by an application of binomial theorem. Noting that $l > 2$:

$$n+k > (k+1)^l =\sum_{j=0}^l \binom ljk^j > \binom ll k^l+\binom l1 k^1=k^l+lk$$

Hence $n > k^l+(l-1)k > k^l$.

Now for (ii), it is indeed by sum of geometric series.

However the first term is not $1$, but $\dfrac {kl}{2n}$. This gives

$$ l\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} (\frac{kl}{2n})^{i-1}= l \cdot \frac{\frac{kl}{2n}}{1-\frac{kl}{2n}} = l \cdot \frac{kl}{2n-kl}=\frac{kl^2}{2n-kl}$$

as expected.

Comment: Sad to see that the issue you spoke of on Meta has not been resolved...

Comment: Horrible situation mate, can't describe the whole story, but there are other, for example vlad has been banned untill 18 th nov, for voting irregularity but the authority is not doing anything for down-vote.